# A weird thing about Sublime Text 2 installed

Tags: 12.10, appmenu

I downloaded sublime text 2, unpacked it to `/opt/sublime` and created a link of `/opt/sublime/sublime_text` (executable) in `/usr/bin` so now I can just call it by typing "`sublime`" in console.

But it's not appeared in applications list: if I type sublime there, it won't be shown. Only if type `sublime_text`, I will see it. But there is more: when I click on it, it won't launch, nothing won't happen at all!

Besides, if I lock it `Launcher`, I won't be able to launch it: I close it, when I click on it on the `Launcher` panel, but it doesn't launch and nothing happens!

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put a `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications` (for all user) or `~/.local/share/applications` (for current user).

Here is custom desktop file, save it as `sublime.desktop` and put in the above location.

(`gksu nautilus` for root access in case you want to put it for all user)

**Change the `Exec` & `Icon` entry as per your path**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Sublime Text 2
Exec="/opt/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text" %F
MimeType=text/plain;
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=sublime_text
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;TextEditor;Development;
Actions=New;

[Desktop Action New]
Name=New Editor Window
Exec="/opt/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text" --new-window
```

<sub>[Source](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=3457)</sub>

Comment: that's good. but doesn't it create a quick launch icon on a desktop as well? actually it doesn't.

Comment: No it doesn't create shortcut. desktop files are for searching in unity & locking at launcher. To create shortcut you need to drag the icon to desktop. See [How to create a desktop shortcut in Unity?](http://askubuntu.com/q/67925)

Comment: @Web-E How come you're not using \ on the space characters in the path for Exec? Shouldn't it be `/opt/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text`?

Comment: No you [don't need escape sequence for `EXEC` key when value is quoted](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables).Also can see [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/175567/35775). BTW the escape sequence for space in `desktop` file is `\s`

Answer (score 2):

I've been using PPA from webupdate. Here's how to install

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/sublime-text-20-stable-released-ppa.html