# Sublime Text launcher not working

Tags: unity, launcher

[A weird thing about Sublime Text 2 installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276693/a-weird-thing-about-sublime-text-2-installed)

I installed Sublime Text, followed above link and created sublime.desktop in my /usr/share/applications folder. I edited it as suggested. This is what is present in that file(after editing).

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Sublime Text 2
*#Only KDE 4 seems to use GenericName, so we reuse the KDE strings.*
*#From Ubuntu's language-pack-kde-XX-base packages, version 9.04-20090413.*
GenericName=Text Editor 
Exec=sublime
Terminal=false
Icon=/usr/lib/Sublime Text 2/Icon/48x48/sublime_text.png
Type=Application
Categories=TextEditor;IDE;Development
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow
[NewWindow Shortcut Group]
Name=New Window
Exec="/opt/Sublime\ Text\ 2 /sublime_text" --new-window
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Even now, the launcher icon is not working. How do I solve this issue?

Specifications: Ubuntu 12.04LTS and Unity

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Sublime T2 
Comment=Best text editor ;)
Exec=/opt/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text
Icon=/opt/Sublime\ Text\ 2/Icon/128x128/sublime_text.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Version=1.0
```

I'm also using ubuntu 12.04, unity.

The icon path isn't working because you have spaces in the file path and you need to have a backslash - known as "\" before the space.

Comment: This worked for me too, but from where did you get this setup ?